# Updating GoDaddy's PHP versions through SSH

Tags: php, ssh

So I'm using GoDaddy (Deluxe/shared/linux) for hosting, but the PHP there only goes up to 5.3.2, and that's way too far back for me. I'd have to change so much of my project's code to get it to work with that version...

Is it possible to SSH into my server, and type something like:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
```

or would that just make a mess of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5

This will install PHP 5.4